# TDictionary using pointers

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Say that I have the following record:

```
   type
     TTest = record
       test1 : TTest1;
       test2 : TTest2;
       test3 : TTest3;
   end;
   pTTest = ^TTest;
   TDictestDictionary = TDictionary<integer,pTTest>;
    testDictionary : TDictestDictionary
```

Will it be sufficient to write

```
   testDictionary := TDictionary<integer,pTTest>.Create;
```

and then add the items like:

```
   testDictionary.AddOrSetValue(1,pValue);
```

or need to initialize pValue ?

But then what happens when:

```
   GetMem(pValue, Value);
   testDictionary.AddOrSetValue(1,pValue);
   FreeMem(pValue);
```

will the items remove the data pointed by pValue ?

Please Help

Also, on the same line of thought, can I have something like this:

```
Type
  myClass = class(TObject)

  private
    FTest : TDictestDictionary ;

 public 
   property propFTest : TDictestDictionary  read getFTest() write setFTest()
```

but then how I write getFTest() setFTest()

Help.
Thank you

Comment: But why on Earth do you want to store the pointers?

Comment: @Jens, because making a copy of the records might be wasteful and difficult to maintain ? Imagine that you can store the records in a plain array and make as much *views* as you want by using pointers. Yes, you must keep them in synch with those *views*, but you would have to do it for *views* having record copies as well.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt without pointers code like `testDictionary[1].test1 = ...` will create copy of record and will not affect value in dictionary. In such cases you need to store record pointers

Comment: Ofcause then whay not use a class and TObjectDictionary. That makes memory management easier, and gives you the power of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to store pointers in your container, then you will need to allocate the memory at some point. If you deallocate the memory when the container still contains a reference to that memory, then the container's reference is useless. It is known as a **stale pointer**. Invariably, holding stale pointers means your code is defective.

There seems to me to be no need to use pointers here. You can declare the dictionary like this:

```
TDictionary<Integer, TTest>
```

That container holds copies of your records, and so manages the lifetime automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree David. I see no need for pointers here. Use a class and a `TObjectDictionary` then you can create as many views as you want and memory management is still easy: One `TObjectDictionary` owns the classes the other `TObjectDictionary` or `TList<>`are just views presending your data different.

Here is a unit ment for **inspiration**.

```
unit TestDictionaryU;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TTest1 = class
  end;

  TTest2 = class
  end;

  TTest3 = class
  end;

  TTest = class
    test1: TTest1;
    test2: TTest2;
    test3: TTest3;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TTestDictonary = class(TObjectDictionary<Integer, TTest>)
  public
    constructor Create;
    function AddTest : TTest;
  end;

implementation

{ TTest }

constructor TTest.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  test1 := TTest1.Create;
  test2 := TTest2.Create;
  test3 := TTest3.Create
end;

destructor TTest.Destroy;
begin
  test1.Free;
  test2.Free;
  test3.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{ TTestDictonary }

function TTestDictonary.AddTest: TTest;
begin
  Result := TTest.Create;
end;

constructor TTestDictonary.Create;
begin
  inherited Create([doOwnsValues]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why use a class? Surely this is a record?

Comment: Records don't require use of pointers. No pointers with the type in my answer.

Comment: Correct but in your example, you can't work directly with properties on the elements in the list

Comment: Yes you can. Use the `List` property.

Comment: If it where a Tlist<T> yes.

Comment: Er yes! Still this still feels like a value type to me